# How to use SecureString SSM parameter store to create EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I used to create EC2 using ppk file with Terraform code.

```
resource "aws_instance" "my_ec2" {
...
key_name = var.my_ppk_file_name
...

}
```

But now the infra team have advised us to stop using SSH keys and instead have created SecureString parameter on AWS SSM; they're asking us to use this parameter to create EC2's going ahead.

when I ran

```
  aws ssm get-parameters --names my_keypair_name --with-decrypt
```

, this gives a secure string

Is it possible for me to create a ppk file using this output which I can use to create EC2 using Terraform?

If not, then how do I use the SSM param SecureString in my Terraform code to create new EC2 instances?

Please advise.

Comment: So the private key is in the SSM?

Comment: Yes. That's what the infra team tells me.

Comment: So can you clarify what were you doing before, because `key_file` is incorrect argument for `aws_instance`.

Comment: I was using `key_name` and not `key_file` - sorry - my bad.

Comment: So how do I use this SecureString parameter on SSM in my Terraform code to create a new EC2 instance. That's my query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use data source [aws_ssm_parameter](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ssm_parameter) to get your key and they create key pair using [aws_key_pair](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/key_pair). For example, as some adjustment may still be required:

```
# get the key from ssm 
# key will be in PLAIN TEXT in your state file!
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "privagtekey" {
  name = "my_keypair_name"
}

# create new key pair
resource "aws_key_pair" "key" {
  public_key = aws_ssm_parameter.privagtekey.value
}

# use the new key in your instance
resource "aws_instance" "my_ec2" {
...
key_name = aws_key_pair.key.id
...

}
```

But as I indicated, the private key will end up in **plain text** your state file. So it depends how your state file is managed. If its remote state (e.g., S3) with strict access controls then it can be fine.

Comment: Thanks much. Is it possible to create a physical ppk file from this SecureString SSM parameter?

Comment: @Biju Yes, using [local_file](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file).

Comment: @Biju How did it go with local_file?